# How to use history using withRouter outside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new to react router and I'm having few difficulties. I have no problems using history inside a component. Howver, I have a function outside the said component and it can't detect history. I tried alot of things but to no avail. It gives me a `history is undefined` error

**UserAvatar.js**

```
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

const signOut = (history) => {

    console.log(history);
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    history.replace('/sign-in');
};


export class UserAvatar extends Component {
    render() {
        const content = (
            <div>
                <p>Content</p>
                <Button className="sign-out" onClick={() => signOut(this.props.history)}>Sign-out</Button>
            </div>
        );

export default withRouter(UserAvatar, signOut)
```

any ideas would be of great help Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) library to manually create the history outside of your component tree and give that to your `Router` component. This way you can import the `history` object wherever you need it.

**Example**

```
// history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();

// index.js
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/user">User</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="/user" component={UserAvatar} />
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Hello! from what I understood, history should be able to redirect you to a component(?) when I tried this implementation, the url does change but the component stays the same. Could you please give me some insights on why this happens?

Comment: @Jason Yes, `history.replace` or `history.push` should render the routes that match the new url. I'm not sure what goes wrong for you. Maybe you could create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or something similar to show your issue?

Comment: So I think it would be better not to use the hook ```useHistory``` once you opt for this approach, right? 
Or do you think that I could also use ```useHistory``` despite passing a "custom" history to my Router component?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with signout function definition. You are making history as local variable to your function.
Remove param history from signout method. this should help atleast to print it correctly.

```
const signOut = () => { // remove hestory from hear as its a globally available.

    console.log(history);
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    history.replace('/sign-in');
};
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response. I tried doing this and I get a `unexpected use of history` error. I know this might be a noobie question but how would I refer to history in this case? this.props.history or just history? just history doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package `history`

import it in your file
`import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'`;
then use it like this

`createBrowserHistory().push('/')`;
then you can reload the dom
`window.location.reload()`;`