# react redux: private route not rendering layout

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

Code Sandbox link: [image: Edit broken-worker-9xmm7]

[and trying to follow this article](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/03/02/react-hooks-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example#authentication-reducer-js)

On successful `login(/auth/login)`, the user should be routed to the `dashboard(/admin/summary)`. If the login is successful, I am also storing an `access token`.

I have a `PrivateRoute` component for this. The problem is that on successful login, the URL is getting updated but the component is not getting rendered.

PS: about the dashboard, this is a single page application so, the dashboard has topbar, sidebar, and the right content and altogether these things are coupled inside `<AdminLayout/>`. So, in my `AppRouter`, I have to render the  `<AdminLayout/>` and just any one component.

All the react and redux code is included in the code sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your code you create your own `history` object (it happens in you `history.js` file, when you call `createBrowserHistory()`) but doesn't pass it to your `Router`, nothing happens.

There are 2 possible solutions:

**1. Don't create a `history` object yourself, but use `useHistory` hook inside your component**

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-brattain-quwlb)

With this approach, you should remove `history.push` from `login.actions.js` (which imports `history`) and use `history.push` in `Login.js` (which uses `useHistory` hook):

```
// login.actions.js
...
loginService.login(userid, password, rememberPassword).then(
    (userid) => {
      dispatch(success(userid, password, rememberPassword));
      // history.push(from); <-- commented out!
    },
    (error) => { ... }
  );
};
...
```

```
// Login.js

function handleSubmit(e) {
   ...
   const { from } = {
     from: { pathname: "/admin/summary" }
   };
   history.push(from) // <-- added!
   dispatch(loginActions.login(inputs, from));
   ...
}
```

`useHistory` exposes the `history` object of `BrowserRouter` (I think this is implied in [this official blog post](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/)).

**2. Create a `history` object yourself, but pass it to a `Router` component**

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-heisenberg-kw4ms)

This approach would require you to make several changes:

1. Creating the `history` object on your own means you become responsible to provide it to a router component, but it can't be a `BrowserRouter`, but the base `Router` component (see these Github answers: [1](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7209#issuecomment-602285546), [2](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4059#issuecomment-254437084)).
2. Once you import `Router` (instead of `BrowserRouter`), you need to get rid of any `useLocation` and `useHistory` imports, otherwise you'll get errors.
3. I also had to unify the `history` object export and imports, so that it is exported as the default export (i.e., `export default history`), and it is imported as the default import (i.e., `import history from "./history";` instead of `import { history } from "./history"`)

(P.S: this approach can be seen implemented elsewhere on SO, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51192811/how-to-use-history-using-withrouter-outside-component) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50926759/3002584) (the latter explicitly installs `history`, but it's not needed in your case).

Comment: thanks for this. Actually I do have installed `history`. Update: it's now kinda loading the `layout` ie. click login-> blank page with correct `className` in `<body>` is loaded. But not the contents of the page. Now, these contents are coming from `AdminLayout` and I have just updated the sandbox with it. ` <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin">
          <AdminLayout {...props} />
        </PrivateRoute>` and this is how I trying to load that in `AppRouter`. Any suggestion where I am going wrong.

Comment: Note that your sandbobox doesn't list `history` as a dependency, that's why I said that in your case it's not necessary. Regarding your update, I don't see it, and you better post the updated sandbox link here in the comments. Please do not remove your original question link, as it would invalidate my answer. I also think that it would be fair to accept my answer, and I would then try help you with your follow up question.

Comment: UPDATED sandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-worker-9xmm7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=editor&file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure that's the updated sandbox? I don't see either my answer's approach 1 or approach 2 implemented.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the approach 1 worked for me. I just added `AdminLayout` code and updated related imports in `AppRouter`

Comment: But is approach 1 implemented in the sandbox you linked to in your comment? I don't think so, because `<Dashboard>` is not displayed.

Comment: Then of course it won't work :) plus, I don't see the implementation of `AdminLayout` in your updated link (it's also not present in your linked article, so I assume it's your own implementation). Now, once you'd add it, you should also pay attention to the fact that it is placed under a `Switch`, so navigating to `Dashboard` vs `AdminLayout` should be handled by additional code, probably in `PrivateRoute`.

Comment: `1)` `Admin.js` is AdminLayout. its related import is commented out in `AppRouter`. `2)` I also updated my question's desc with the article I had followed to write my own code. `3).` can you please, elaborate  `placed under a Switch, so navigating to Dashboard vs AdminLayout should be handled by additional code, probably in PrivateRoute` this point. thanks a ton !!

Comment: Sorry, `Admin.js` has many imports that are not present as files. Please uncomment `Admin.js` import, then make sure that your code compiles, and then I'll try to help you further.

Comment: sure. done. updated link:  https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-worker-9xmm7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=editor&file=/src/AppRouter.js